# Making columns the same height while contatining object taking all available space

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Here is CSS playground: https://www.bootply.com/HHeQ3n0EbT

[image]

```
<div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col ltg-column-parent">
                        Column
                        <div class="ltg-column-inside">
                            <div class="task-box">
                                content
                            </div>
                          <div class="task-box">
                                content
                            </div>
                          <div class="task-box">
                                content
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="task-table-bottom-buttons">
                            <button>+</button>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                  <div class="col ltg-column-parent">
                        Column
                        <div class="ltg-column-inside">
                            <div class="task-box">
                                content
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="task-table-bottom-buttons">
                            <button>+</button>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                  <div class="col ltg-column-parent">
                        Column
                        <div class="ltg-column-inside">
                            <div class="task-box">
                                content
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="task-table-bottom-buttons">
                            <button>+</button>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
.ltg-column-parent {
    margin: 1px;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: lightgray;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
}

.ltg-column-inside {
    background-color: rgb(151, 151, 151);
    height: 100%;
    /* border: white solid 1px; */
}

.task-box {
    width: 10rem;
    height: 6rem;
    color: black; 
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    border-left: 7px solid yellow;
    padding-left: 1rem;
    padding-top: 1rem;
    display: inline-block;
}

.task-table-bottom-buttons {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

I'm making some kind of kanban table, where you can create tasks (white boxes with yellow border) and drag&drop them between columns.

- Column is a box with `lightgray` background.
- Darkgray div is where I can put/drag task boxes

Now, there are a few problems here. Darkgray box with "+" button are moving outside its parent lightgray div. This is because darkgray div is set to `height: 100%` as I want it to take all available space in column. If I delete that, darkgray div shrinks and columns have less space that tasks can be placed.

I want to accomplish a few things:

- columns have to have the same height **if** they lay next to each other (if screen is smaller and columns are placed below, then the same height is not necessary)
- "+" button have to be sticked to the bottom of the last task (or entire column if it will be easier)
- darkgray div should be as big as possible without artificially chaging height of column (as user have to have place to drop tasks).

What should I do to make it look correctly?

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for me:

```
.ltg-column-inside {
    background-color: rgb(151, 151, 151);
    border: white solid 1px;
    display: flex;
    overflow: auto;
    height: auto;

}
```

[image]

Comment: Not exactly what I meant. Here is how it looks like with different task numbers: https://imgur.com/a/N0HZjG0

Comment: and "+" button is still outside lightgray. On your screenshot it's correct. Have you pasted here all changes you've made?

Comment: add min-height: 95px to .ltg-column-inside and it works

Comment: also, add width: fill to .task-box if you dont want grey space

Answer (score 0):

use `dispaly:flex` to `.ltg-column-inside`

```
.ltg-column-inside{
dispaly:flex
}
```

if you don't want the grey section **remove** this:

```
.task-box{
    height: 6rem;
}
```

Comment: Not exactly what I meant. Here is how it looks like with different task numbers: https://imgur.com/a/N0HZjG0